# Android full screen app too dark

Tags: android

I changed the manifest of my Android app to make the app full screen on my GS3. On a non-full screen mode, the app has a white back ground. However, on full screen mode, it becomes black. I was wondering if there is a way to keep the app white and bright even in full screen mode

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can set a custom theme for your app in manifest as white background. Then if wont have any default behaviour. Currently it may be picking default android theme..

```
<style name="CustomTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light"> 
            <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/custom_theme_color</item>
            <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/custom_theme_color</item> 
</style>
```

Comment: Create a theme like this and set in manifest:   <style name="CustomTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/custom_theme_color</item>
    <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/custom_theme_color</item>
</style>

Comment: I was trying to do that but could not. I will try to learn how to indent in stackflow and will do :) thanks for pointin though..

Comment: CTRL K works for me when I try to indent answer, but for comments in never works for me.

Comment: In comments you need back tick. The key beside number 1. So, you can `highlight words like this`. However, it is recommended that if you are posting a block of code rather than a single line, you make an edit to your answer and  post it there. Makes it much more legible.

Comment: Thanks for guiding. Will keep it in mind to keep the thread more helpful and readable for others :)

Comment: Hi.. In case it helped to solve the issue, please accept the answer so that others can get to know the correct answer easily. Thanks :)